# OnclientClick aspnetForm.target ='_blank' multiply

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I have ImageButton control on my ASP.Net page

```
<asp:ImageButton  ID="img1"  
                  ImageUrl="..." 
                  runat="server" 
                  OnClick="On_Click"
                  OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"/>
```

And On_Click method in code behind which performs redirect:

```
 Response.Redirect(someUrl);
```

The problem is that I can use this button only once, after I press to the ImageButton next time nothing happen. 
How can I use my button to open new tab multiply times?

Comment: same **URL** for the multiple times or _different_ urls. ??

Comment: the same URL for the multiply times

Comment: can u  show the code-behind of `OnClick` ? also show the `OnClientClick` code